# What does the name "Ktor" stand for?

Tags: ktor

I suppose the "K" in Ktor stands for Kotlin, the programming language the Ktor framework uses to build asynchronous servers and clients, which itself is named after a Russian island [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_Island).

But what does "tor" mean? Does it stand for anything? Or is it just a name? Tried looking for anything with regards to this in the documentation and searched through stack and didn't find anything.

Comment: Why don't you ask JetBrains?  The question is probably off-topic here and they're the only ones who can provide an authoritative answer.  If there is one.

Comment: Why would I ask JetBrains where fewer people (if any) would be able to read the answer when I could ask it on Stack Overflow where thousands of people who might wonder the same thing could come across it?
Not to mention that a lot of developers browse Stack Overflow including Ktor devs themselves, as evident by the @Aleksei Tirman who answered the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ktor is the word `ctor` (constructor) where the first letter replaced with `K` (from Kotlin).

Comment: Do you have any authorative source for this?

Comment: Does it count if I'm a member of the Ktor development team?

Comment: Why not - please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: If you are a member of the development team, and you know that is the real meaning / explanation for the name, then it counts.  But it would still be nice if you cited a **written** source; e.g. something in the Ktor FAQ.

Comment: ...and if this is not already part of the FAQ (or any other part of documentation), it would be nice to add it there too